# Converting function's arguments to array-like object

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, bind, slice

I was told that it is useful for making the 'arguments' object a true array and also for creating a copy of an existing array. However, is it necessary to convert to array-like object ? and what's the advantage of doing that ?

```
function toArray(obj) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(obj);
}

function bind(scope, fn) {
    return function() {
         // why not just return fn.apply(scope, arguments);  ?
         return fn.apply(scope, toArray(arguments));
    };
}
```

I know the good things about 'arguments' object is that it contains the 'length' property, so we can convert to an array-like object, but when I tested it by passing in an object like

```
x = { 
     'a': 'a', 
     'tt': 'tt', 
     '2':'2', 
      length:3 
};

toArray(x); // [undefined x 2, 2]
```

it returns an array with `undefined` element in it, is it because their keys are not numeric ?

Comment: *"why not just `return fn.apply(scope, arguments);`"* ... Given your example, that's exactly what you should do. There's no reason to do `toArray(arguments)` there, unless you wanted to pass a subset of the args.

Comment: ...it looks like your example is sort of a *"mini-bind"* function. In a typical `.bind()`, one may `.concat()` the passed `arguments` to the end of the bound `arguments`, which would require an Array in order to flatten the two into a single flat Array. Like: `return fn.apply(scope, orig_args.concat(toArray(arguments)));`

Comment: @CrazyTrain what would be the orig_args ? can you give an example please

Comment: Basically, it would be any arguments passed to the `bind()` function that come after `scope` and `fn`. So at the top of the `bind()` function, you'd do `var orig_args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);`. Now any arguments after the second one will be held in the `orig_args`, so when the returned function is invoked, those arguments will be passed first, and any arguments passed directly to the returned function will be added after the bound ones.

Comment: ...basically like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bwMbE/1/ I changed the `toArray()` function to receive a second argument that sets the start index of the slice.

Answer (score 0):

if you had done:

```
x={1:1,2:1,0:55,length:3};
toArray(x);

// result [55, 1, 1]
```

an array is going to expect the keys to be numbers.
so it goes through looks at 0... undefined
looks at 1... undefined
looks at 2... '2'

So yes, it's because their keys are not numeric.

hope this helps